# tkinter gui which loads a flie and can print out the file name

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter

I am starting with python and I already created a nice plotting function with `matplotlib`. Now I want to insert the function into a GUI using tkinter.
As I learned from youtube and this forum I should use classes.
Unfortunately I have some problems with that. What I have so far (where I do not understand everything in detail) is:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

LARGE_FONT=('Verdana',12)


class XPSPlotApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args,**kwargs)
        container=tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)#0 is min size
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)


        #adding a menubar#
        self.menuBar = tk.Menu(master=self)
        self.filemenu = tk.Menu(self.menuBar, tearoff=0)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.browse_file)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Quit!", command=self.quit)
        self.menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)
        self.config(menu=self.menuBar)

        self.frames={}

        for F in (HRXPSPlotter, SurveyXPSPlotter):

            frame=F(container,self)

            self.frames[F]=frame

            frame.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(HRXPSPlotter)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    #Question if it should be here because maybe overwrites the filename   form other window?
    def browse_file(self):
        self.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "E:/Images",title = "choose your file",filetypes = (("txt files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
        print(self.filename)
    def printFN(self):
        print(self.filename)


class HRXPSPlotter(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        lable=tk.Label(self,text='Sart Page',font=LARGE_FONT)
        lable.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        #button to go to another page
        button1=tk.Button(self, text='Visit Page 1',command=lambda:controller.show_frame(SurveyXPSPlotter))
        button1.pack()

class SurveyXPSPlotter(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        lable=tk.Label(self,text='Page One',font=LARGE_FONT)
        lable.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1=tk.Button(self, text='Back to Page 1',command=lambda:controller.show_frame(HRXPSPlotter))
        button1.pack()

app=XPSPlotApp()
app.mainloop()
```

The program has two pages (because I want to use different plotter) and a menu which can open a file from a directory.

1. Now I want to implement a function which plots the `filename`+`filepath` when I  click a button, but I do not get it work? The problem is simply that I do not really know where I have to define the function — in the `__init__` or in the subclasses? and also...
2. How the `command=lambda:controller` works, it is still magic for me!
3. Why are the subclasses (e.g. `pageOne`) methods of `tk.Frame` and not `tk.Tk` like the `__init__`?

Comment: `command=lambda:controller.show_frame(SurveyXPSPlotter)` is like `def command(): return controller.show_frame(SurveyXPSPlotter)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to address all your three sub-questions directly because it would wind-up being a whole mini-tutorial on `tkinter`. However I can show you how to add a `Button` to do the plotting. Note especially the lines with the comment **`# ADDED`** on them.

Below a modified version of your code with a number of things added showing where and how to put a plotting function function could be put in. I've also changed the coding style so it follows the [**PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) more closely and is much more readable.

In a several spots I also changed the name of variables to make it clearer how this kind of gui architecture based on `tkinter` operates.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
LARGE_FONT=('Verdana', 12)


class XPSPlotApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # 0 is min size
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Add menubar and subcommands.
        self.menuBar = tk.Menu(master=self)
        self.filemenu = tk.Menu(self.menuBar, tearoff=0)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.browse_file)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Plot", command=self.plot_file)  # ADDED
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Quit!", command=self.quit)
        self.menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)
        self.config(menu=self.menuBar)

        self.frames={}

        for FrameSubclass in (HRXPSPlotter, SurveyXPSPlotter):
            frame = FrameSubclass(container, self)  # create class instance.
            self.frames[FrameSubclass] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(HRXPSPlotter)

    def show_frame(self, subclass):
        frame = self.frames[subclass]
        frame.tkraise()

    def browse_file(self):
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            initialdir="E:/Images", title="Choose your file",
            filetypes=(("text files", "*.txt"), ("all files", "*.*"))
        )
        print(self.filename)

    def plot_file(self):  # ADDED
        try:
            print('Plotting:', self.filename)
        except AttributeError:
            print('No filename has been selected to plot!')


class HRXPSPlotter(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text='Start Page', font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        # Button to go to another page.
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text='Visit Page 1',
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SurveyXPSPlotter))
        button1.pack()


class SurveyXPSPlotter(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text='Page One', font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        # Button to go to another page.
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text='Back to Page 1',
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HRXPSPlotter))
        button1.pack()


app=XPSPlotApp()
app.mainloop()
```

The `command=lambda: controller.show_frame(<tk.Frame subclass>)` arguments used to construct the `tk.Buttons` creates an anonymous function which calls `controller.show_frame(<tk.Frame subclass>)` when the corresponding button is pressed (as opposed to it happening as the `Button` itself is created).

The `show_frame()` function looks up the `Frame` subclass *instance* in the `self.frames` dictionary that was created in the `XPSPlotApp` class `__init__()` method and "raises" it so it becomes as the top-most frame displayed (which effectively hides all the rest of them which are the same size and at the same position but now "below" it).

Comment: Thx. for the answer! I my question was not really correct. So wat I want is to use the Path+filename stored in self.filename in the other classes to load data in every window and plot them with a function stored in another py file. The problem is i dont know how to use the self.filename in the 'subClass' (e.g. HRXPSPlotter)? thx.

Comment: MatthiasK: My example code shows using `self.filename` in the `XPSPlotApp.plot_file()` method that was added. What more do you want? What's an example of "using" it in another class? What other class? Each `tk.Frame` subclass receives a `controller` argument when it's constructed. That object is an instance of `XPSPlotApp` and will have a `filename` attribute once the `"Open"` menu item has run the `browse_file()` method.

Comment: What other class: as I said e.g. subclass HRXPSPlotter. I have this function inside HRXPSPlotter $ f=compxpsplot(data='c:/data/file_name.txt'.sizef=15) $ now i want to replace $'c:/data/file_name.txt'$ by the variable stored in self.filename in the superclass. controller.filename does not work also if I define a method in the superclass which returns self.filename it always returns: $AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'filename'$?

Comment: `HRXPSPlotter` is a subclass of `tk.Frame` **not** `XPSPlotApp`, so it will never have a `self.filename` attribute. Your code assigns that to the`XPSPlotApp` **instance** named `app` which is created on the second-to-last line of the code—and it only does that when its `browse_file()` method has been called. If you want to reference this attribute in one of the `tk.Frame` subclass methods, you will need to save the `controller` argument passed to each's `__init__()` function. In other words the attribute is `controller.filename`.

Comment: As I said controller.filename does not work--> output is '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'filename' ...,by the way why does str() not work inside the class? I thought standard lib. is working?

Comment: As I said, the `filename` attribute will not exist until the `browse_file()` method has been executed (by selecting "Open" on the file menu at least once). It won't exist when the instances of the `tk.Frame` subclasses are created in the `XPSPlotApp.__init__()` method. Sorry, but I don't understand your question about `str()` not working.  What `str()`?

Comment: OK thx. I understand now that i have to define an initial value for filename.Then I think one as to update the subclass to show the plot...but how could I do this? Because it still does not work to change the data/shows the plot from the data I selected with open using browse_file(). So I tried to set the plotfunction in an if statement (if (fileIN==True):) and defined a new variable fileIN which I defined inside the __init__ function of XPSPlotApp with fileIN=False and used the brows_file() to set it True

Comment: I solved the problem by using `plot_spectra(self,filename)` and updated it in the `brows_file` function with `self.frames[CompareXPSPlotter].plot_spectra(self.filename)`